# Flask framework, how to use ajax to refresh value

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'm a new with flask and now I need to makes my page dynamic.
That's why I'm trying to send data from JS to Python using the JSON format with AJAX but surfing the web I can't understand how to do it.

Can anyone show me a simple implementation of how AJAX is used on Flask to change the value of a variable every X time?

This my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, flash, jsonify, make_response


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/getdata", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def getdata():
    #get JSON data and change it

    return data


@app.route("/data")
def data():
    # show dynamically the data 

    return render_template("data.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

This is my js function, the gauge array is the value to make dynamic

```
setInterval(
                    ciccio.refreshValue({{gauge[0]}})
                    ,wrapper.refreshValue({{gauge[1]}})
                    ,wrapper1.refreshValue({{gauge[2]}})
                    ,wrapper2.refreshValue({{gauge[3]}})
                    ,wrapper3.refreshValue({{gauge[4]}})
                    ,wrapper4.refreshValue({{gauge[5]}})
                    ,wrapper5.refreshValue({{gauge[6]}})
                    ,wrapper6.refreshValue({{gauge[7]}})
                    ,500);
                )
```

I need to refresh the gauge array

Comment: Can you maybe ask on a specific case that you need? And where you had a problem with it? Because the answer to the question you can learn online.

Comment: it's specific enough? if you need other explaination tell me well

Comment: Please read how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I can answer your question but you first need to understand how to ask one.

Comment: is this a better version?

Comment: Show the request you'd like to 'see' in the backend

Comment: I think to need GET request because the js ask information to server

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved by this code

python:

```
def getdata():
    return jsonify({'results' : sample(range(101), 2)})     # some data from the server


@app.route("/misuratore")
def data():
    return render_template("misuratore.html")
```

javascript

```
setInterval(
    function updateGauge() {

      var updatedData = $.get('/getdata'); //get data from localhost/getdata

      updatedData.done(function(results) {  // when the get are completed launch function that apply the new value

          pippo.refreshValue(results.results[0])  
          pluto.refreshValue(results.results[1])

        });
    },1000);  // every second
```